# How to group records where a subset matches a condition

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, microsoft-reporting

I have created a Microsoft report in VS2008 that displays details of products that are tested in a factory. Relevant fields to this problem are: SerialNumber (int), Pass (bool).
There is also a record ID which means several entries may exist per SerialNumber.

What we would like the report to show is to be grouped where SerialNumbers have never met the condition Pass=True (i.e. actual rejects) and the rest under where at least one record shows Pass=True.

The expression for the grouping currently is "=Fields!Pass.Value" which splits pass and fail records (and are then sorted etc).

Comment: So you want to display SerialNumber - Fail etc first then SerialNumber Pass for all the failed and passed records?

Comment: [This venn diagram should clarify](http://imgur.com/ltygaic)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes up against this and wants to know how I solved it, I added an extra boolean column to the SQL query called 'Reject' which returns true or false and used this to group the report.

As powerful as the reporting can be, it just appears to be quite limited on what it can do with set data beyond `Count`, `CountDistinct` etc.